# Sorting the other keys of a Dictionary based on values of one key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary for medical practices `P`. Each key of the dictionary has a list inside it. I want to sort the other list based on one list. For example:

I have two lists `speciality` and `count`, which are part of dictionary `P`. The length of both the lists are same.

```
speciality = s('Cardiology' , 'Nephrology', 'ENT', 'Oncology').     
count = c(2, 7, 9, 1).

P = {'Speciliaty': speciality, 'Count': count}
```

Let's say, I have sorted the list 'count' in descending order. The list `Speciality` should also be sorted in the same way so that the `Speciality` `'Count'` item matching is not impacted.

```
count = c(9, 7, 2, 1).  
speciality = s('ENT', 'Nephrology', 'Cardiology', 'Oncology').
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` with `sorted` and set `reverse=True` for reversed sorting:

```
speciality = ['Cardiology' , 'Nephrology', 'ENT', 'Oncology']
count = [2, 7, 9, 1]

count, speciality = zip(*[[x, y] for x, y in sorted(zip(count, speciality), reverse=True)])
P = {'Speciliaty': speciality, 'Count': count}

print(P)
# {'Speciliaty': ('ENT', 'Nephrology', 'Cardiology', 'Oncology'), 'Count': (9, 7, 2, 1)}
```

---

FYI, lists in python are represented in square brackets `[]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Austin for quick response. :)

Comment: The individual List 'count' and 'speciality' are sorted in  proper way. But, the Dictionary is not getting printed correctly. Could you please help?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. I updated my answer. Have a look now.

Comment: Is there a chance, that the 'Zip' function would convert the List into a Tuple?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are asking for. Can you show an input and corresponding output you are expecting? If you look , `count` and `speciality` are already tuples after the `zip` operation.

Comment: Yes, they are converted to Tuples. Is there a way, we can stop this and keep them as List only.

Comment: Are you looking for: `P = {'Speciliaty': list(speciality), 'Count': list(count)}` ?

Comment: yes, P  =  {'Speciliaty': ['ENT', 'Nephrology', 'Cardiology', 'Oncology'], 'Count': [9, 7, 2, 1]}

Comment: Try my above comment in your code. It works the way you wanted.

Comment: Lets make some changes to the list as shown below:
'speciality = ['Cardiology' , 'Nephrology', 'Opthalmology', 'ENT', 'Oncology']'
'count = [2, 7, 9, 9, 1]'
After sorting it becomes:
 {'Speciliaty': ['ENT', 'Opthalmology',  'Nephrology', 'Cardiology', 'Oncology'], 'Count': (9, 9, 7, 2, 1)}
How can we make it:
 {'Speciliaty': ['Opthalmology', ENT',  'Nephrology', 'Cardiology', 'Oncology'], 'Count': (9, 9, 7, 2, 1)}

Plz notice the Count of ENT and Opthalmology are same = 9. But, while d output List is generated the ENT comes before Opthalmology. While in input Opthalmology z before ENT.

Comment: Did you understand the requirement ??

Comment: Yes, I understood. This is the output from my code: `{'Speciliaty': ['Opthalmology', 'ENT', 'Nephrology', 'Cardiology', 'Oncology'], 'Count': [9, 9, 7, 2, 1]}`. Isn't this you are looking for? `Opthalmology` comes before `ENT` like it is in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.argsort`

```
indices = np.argsort(count)
count = np.sort(count)
specialty = [specialty[i] for i in indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify whether you already have the dictionary P or if you are building it from the lists in your code. In the case of latter the accepted answer is a way to go. But in general when you have a dictionary with many key, value pairs and you want to sort all of them based on a specific key value pair a cleaner solution is to get a separate list of positions and then use that list to sort the other key value pairs. Example below

```
In [12]: P
Out[12]: 
{'Count': [2, 7, 9, 1],
 'Names': ['Obi', 'Luke', 'Anakin', 'Yoda'],
 'Speciliaty': ['Cardiology', 'Nephrology', 'ENT', 'Oncology']}

In [13]: pos = [ P['Count'].index(elem) for elem in sorted(P['Count'], reverse = True) ]

In [14]: pos
Out[14]: [2, 1, 0, 3]

In [15]: for k in P:                   
    P[k] = [P[k][elem] for elem in pos]
   ....:     

In [16]: P
Out[16]: 
{'Count': [9, 7, 2, 1],
 'Names': ['Anakin', 'Luke', 'Obi', 'Yoda'],
 'Speciliaty': ['ENT', 'Nephrology', 'Cardiology', 'Oncology']}
```